# how to fix it?(it happened when my friend run /stop in chat with the telegram bot)(since then the bot is always gives this error...)

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

```
ruby .\bot.rb
@: /stop
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from ./bot.rb:7:in `<main>'
        7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/bot.rb:32:in `get_updates'
        6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/bot.rb:32:in `loop'
        5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/bot.rb:34:in `block in get_updates'
        4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/bot.rb:34:in `each'
        3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/bot.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in get_updates'
        2: from ./bot.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
        1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/message.rb:16:in `reply'
./bot.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `commands' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  command``
```

the whole code:

```
    require 'telegram_bot'
token ="my bot token"
bot = TelegramBot.new(token: token)

bot.get_updates(fail_silently: true) do |message|
  puts "@#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"
  command = message.get_command_for(bot)

  message.reply do |reply|
    case command
    when /start/i
      reply.text = "All I can do is say hello. Try the /greet command."
    when /greet/i
      greetings = ['bonjour', 'hola', 'hallo', 'sveiki', 'namaste', 'salaam', 'szia', 'halo', 'ciao']
      reply.text = "#{greetings.sample.capitalize}, #{message.from.first_name}!"
    else
      reply.text = "I have no idea what #{commands.inspect} means."
    end
    puts "sending #{reply.text.inspect} to @#{message.from.username}"
    reply.send_with(bot)
  end
end
```

Comment: `commands` should be `command` on this line `reply.text = "I have no idea what #{commands.inspect} means."` **Hint:** the error message tells you "**undefined local variable or method** `commands'" and tells you what line to look at "./bot.rb: **19**" and suggests a change *"Did you mean?  command"*

Comment: @engineersmnky now i have more errors that i don't understand why...

Comment: C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/telegram_bot-0.0.8/lib/telegram_bot/api_response.rb:13:in `initialize': uninitialized constant TelegramBot::ApiResponse::ResponseError (NameError)

Comment: Well there are 2 open tickets for this https://github.com/eljojo/telegram_bot/issues however I would not expect them to be closed since this library has not been updated in 3 years. Maybe look into a different gem all together at this point. That being said if you truly want to use this gem https://github.com/eljojo/telegram_bot/issues/44#issuecomment-489554903 proposes a solution